# Add New Controller to MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I want to add new controller to my MVC application.Here is my screen

[image]

First of all **MovieDBContext** do not exist in this list,

I created New one. When i press Add button,I get this popup error
[image]

Do i need to create Model first? Here is my Model code

```
`public class LogOn
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MovieDBContext");
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

}`
```

My web.config has this code

```
  <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=test;User ID = sa; Password = 123456;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Why do you have db object in your entity? Remove it and it should work.

Comment: I tried that also but no luck....I am having in model bcoz i am doing like this... DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_abc");

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this:

```
 public class LogOn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

    public class LogOnContext : DbContext
{
    public LogOnContext() : base("MovieDBContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<LogOn> LogOns{ get; set; }
}
```

Then **build** project and add a scaffolding item (controller).

You need to change because there's an ambiguous reference:

replace in Edit() method (**after controller scaffolding**):

```
db.Entry(logon).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

with:

```
db.Entry(logon).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

Your Edit method should look like as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="Id,UserName,Password")] LogOn logon)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(logon).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(logon);
    }
```

Comment: Oh God..From where my edit function came?What ever you posted,i do not have in my question...

Comment: You create model first, then build, then scaffolding, then change the Edit method if you get an error like above.

Comment: When i press Add button,I get this popup error...I can not add controller

Answer (score 0):

After you create the model as follows:

```
public class LogOn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class LogOnContext : DbContext
{
    public LogOnContext()
        : base("MovieDBContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<LogOn> LogOns { get; set; }
}
```

and **buil project** when you select Data Context class you select (in scaffolding menu)

**LogOnContext (MvcFirst.Models)** not MvcFirst.Models.DBContext

Comment: I saw in comments bellow that you may have problems with Entity Framework. To uninstall EF:View -> Other windows -> Package Manager Console then run command: Uninstall-Package EntityFramework;To install EF5 use command: Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used entity framework version 6. Then I found that it was happening for EF. Because version 6 does not support scaffolding properly with MVC 4. Then I remove it and replace it with version 5. This tricks may be help you. If it helps please give a vote. Thanks

Comment: How to check that either it is EF 6?..how to remove and install EF5?

Comment: after replace the new version of ef don't forget to change the version of ef in web config

Comment: go to references of your solution. There will be EntityFramework.dll . Right click on it  and see the properties